# How do I evaluate this limit, using Sandwich Theorem?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Using Sandwich Theorem, how can I evaluate the limit for - 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (a^n+b^n)^{1/n}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive quantities and $b$ is greater than $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$b < (a^{n} + b^{n})^{1/n} < 2^{1/n}b$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate this? I am getting an idea but not so sure about it. Please help me out.

Comment: @user574937 If you can show that the inequality is true, than we get the result from $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{1/n} = 2^{\lim_{n\to \infty} 1/n} = 1$ and the sandwitch theorem. To prove the inequality, take $n$th power of both sides and use $a<b$.

Comment: That part was understood. I mean, how did you get upon this conclusion? What and how did you thought?

Comment: @user574937 If you want some intuition of the proof, since $a<b$, $b^{n}$ will be much bigger than $a^{n}$ when $n$ is very large. So in the sequence $(a^{n} + b^{n})^{1/n}$, $a^{n}$ may not affect the limit.